# Applescript: Safari "Do Javascript" No Longer Returns Booleans?

Tags: javascript, applescript, macos-monterey

This used to return either true or false:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.querySelector(\"video\") == null" in document 1
```

However, now, on macOS 12.0.1 on an M1 MBP, it doesn't seem to return anything (missing value) and the following convoluted wrapper seems necessary to get the former result:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set result to do JavaScript "if (document.querySelector(\"video\") == null) {
   1
} else {
   0
}" in document 1
    return result is 1
end tell
```

Another weird thing is that it's *only booleans* that don't get returned. The following returns `3.0`:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "3" in document 1
```

Any idea what changed? Is there a better way to get the boolean result back?

Here is what my Safari Develop tab looks like in case any of those settings are relevant:
[image]

Comment: I just tested `tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.querySelector(\"video\") == null" in document 1` in **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1 and it returns a _boolean_.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Bizarre. How did you run it, @user3439894?

Comment: With **Safari** opened to a default _window_ that just shows the **Favorites**, I previously copied it from your question and pasted it into a new _document_ in **Script Editor** and pressed **⌘R**. In the **Result** _pane_ it returned `true`.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. I’ll try to rule out settings. Maybe something to do with security/privacy...

Comment: @user3439894, would you mind sharing if Script Editor has any Privacy permissions in System Preferences? Also, what are your Safari Developer permissions? I'll add mine to the question

Comment: Having **Script Editor** added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** checked on the **Develop** _menu_ in **Safari** is **SOP** as without it's too limited in what it can do.

Comment: Okay, yes I have those enabled. The weird thing is that it's *only booleans* that don't return. I'll add to the question

Comment: Here is a screen shot from **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1 and **Script Editor** running the **AppleScript** _code_: https://i.imgur.com/c6N3bVs.png

Comment: I have the same issue but I am on 12.1. I have the mentioned permissions set.  I've worked around it by breaking my common handler into 2. 1. on runScriptPlain(scriptText) - orig implementation intended if no return is expected, and 2. on runScript(scriptText) 
`set montereyFix to "var jsresult = (" & scriptText & ");if (typeof(jsresult) === 'boolean') { jsresult ? 'true' : 'false'} else jsresult;"`
`runScriptPlain(montereyFix)`. Boolean result is now "true" or "false".

Comment: Given that this is working on Monterey for others, I wonder if it's an M1 issue? I updated the question to clarify that's where I'm seeing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the issue is happening, but here's a temporary workaround in case it helps:

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    set result to do JavaScript "try {
    var jsResult = document.querySelector(\"video\").paused;

    switch (jsResult) {
    case true:
        jsResult = 'js2as-true';
        break;
    case false:
        jsResult = 'js2as-false';
    }
jsResult
}
catch(err) {
'js2as-error' + err.message
}" in document 1
    
    if (result = "js2as-true") then
        return true
    else if (result = "js2as-false") then
        return false
    else if (result starts with "js2as-error") then
        set errMsg to text 12 thru -1 of result
        error errMsg
    else
        return result
    end if
end tell
```

One limitation is that it's hard to make generic because you need to explicitly store the return value from the appropriate statement. Another approach might be to insert the script into an anonymous function, but then you'd have to explicitly `return aValue`